# With PIL can I combine two (or more) bands in a customizable way?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to 'decompose' an `Image` (i.e. `split()`), modify one of the channels by *combining* it with another one and re-'compose' (i.e. `merge()`) them again.

This example should highlight edges by mapping them onto the RED-channel using the feature I wish existed:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
base = Image.open("example.jpg")
base.show()
```

[image: base image]

```
edges = (base
    .convert("L")
    .filter(ImageFilter.Kernel((3, 3), (-1, -1, -1, -1, 8,-1, -1, -1, -1), 1, 0))
    .point(lambda p: 255 if p > 10 else 0))
edges.show()
```

[image: edges]

```
r, g, b = base.split()

# now I want the blue channel/band for each pixel to be whatever respective
# pixel is brighter on a given set of bands

# this is what I want to do, but `combine()` does not exist
b_with_edges = Image.combine((r, edges), lambda pixels: max(pixels))
# instead - for the example I'm dropping blue and take just the edges
b_with_edges = edges

new_image = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b_with_edges))
new_image.show()
```

[image: combined image with edge highlighting]

Of course I can manually iterate through all pixels and combine them manually. From what I've seen from `PIL` it seems to be a quite well developed and flexible library, so I expect there to be some built-in way..

**Update**:

Since CrazyChucky's answer works quite well for this use case, I dare to add a distilled version:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageChops
base = Image.open("example.jpg").reduce(1)
r, g, b = base.split()
edges = (base
    .convert("L")
    .filter(ImageFilter.Kernel((3, 3), (-1, -1, -1, -1, 8,-1, -1, -1, -1), 1, 0))
    .point(lambda p: 255 if p > 10 else 0))
image_with_edge_highlighting = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, ImageChops.lighter(b, edges)))
image_with_edge_highlighting.show()
```

Comment: Not sure what your objection is to the `ImageChops.lighter()` method, but you may like to look at `ImageMath.eval()` here to see if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/69972396/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell They didn't know about `ImageChops.lighter` when first asking the question, but it seems they're ideally looking for something more general purpose, rather than just for this particular case. I haven't noticed `ImageMath.eval` before, that looks much close to what they were talking about! (Or for that matter NumPy, as your linked image also shows.)

Comment: @Mark - can you turn this into an answer? (Otherwise I have to give the points to myself) I'll add some code to the question so you don't have to do the work

Comment: It's ok, you're welcome to take my comment and make it into an answer or use it any way you like... and grab the points too. I haven't really worked out what sort of solution you are looking for so it's better if I don't write it, and if I let you write it up and I'll look forward to upvoting it when I see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [CrazyChucky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12975140/crazychucky)'s answer is quite sophisticated and it solves the example use case provided in the question even better than a generic solution (for being more clear and probably a bit faster), you can use [`ImageMath.eval()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageMath.html#PIL.ImageMath.eval) as stated by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell).

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageMath

base = Image.open("example.jpg")
edges = (base
    .convert("L")
    .filter(ImageFilter.Kernel((3, 3), (-1, -1, -1, -1, 8,-1, -1, -1, -1), 1, 0))
    .point(lambda p: 255 if p > 10 else 0))

image_with_edge_highlighting = Image.merge(
    "RGB",
    (r, g, ImageMath.eval(
        "convert(max(b, edges), 'L')", b=b, edges=edges)))
image_with_edge_highlighting.show()
```

[image: recomposed image with combined blue-channel]

Answer (score 5):

What you describe in this particular case sounds like [`ImageChops.lighter`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html#PIL.ImageChops.lighter):

```
from PIL import ImageChops

b_with_edges = ImageChops.lighter(r, edges)
```

It produces a new image using whichever pixel is lighter (has a higher value) from the two given images.

After merging as in your code, I get the following result:

[image: Output image]

That said... while the `ImageChops` module has quite a few useful functions, I'm not aware of a more general-purpose, customizable function that accepts a callable as you describe. Such a function, if it existed, could be useful, but would probably not be very performant. It would essentially be a wrapper around a `for` loop, iterating at the Python level rather than C—much like Pandas' [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method.

([`point`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.point), which you've already demonstrated in your question, is the closest thing I know of... but of course it operates on only a single image, using a lookup table.)

You could implement it like this, directly accessing and setting pixels through the [`PixelAccess`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html#pixelaccess) class returned by each image's [`load`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.load) method:

```
def custom_image_combine(images, fn):
    width, height = images[0].size
    return_image = Image.new(images[0].mode, (width, height))
    return_image_access = return_image.load()
    accessors = [image.load() for image in images]
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            return_image_access[x, y] = fn(
                accessor[x, y] for accessor in accessors
            )
    return return_image

b_with_edges = custom_image_combine((r, edges), max)
```

Note that you can simply provide `max`, rather than a `lambda` that uses it.